# snmp version 3 client android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to use simple snmp get in android.I found the code for java and try to use it in android.I also attach snmp4j.jar file for android.But I got the NullPointer Exception and I don't get the output.If anybody have any idea or code for how to use snmp in android then please suggest me..